# How to paramatise string length in Pydantic custom validators

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm looking to move some data cleansing code into Pydantic data models. So far the custom validation is working fine. However I would like to specify a max length of a string as a parameter, and just truncate anything longer than the max. How can I do that?

A sample base class:

```
class MyBaseClass(BaseModel, extra='ignore'):

    def get_int_or_orig_value(val: any, validator: ValidationInfo) -> int:
        # validation code here

    def get_number_or_orig_value(val: any, validator: ValidationInfo) -> int:
        # validation code here

    def sanitise_plain_text(s: str, validator: ValidationInfo) -> str:
        # validation code here        
        # HOW CAN I ACCESS A MAX_LEN PARAMETER e.g.?
        return s[:max_len]
      

    SafeNumber: ClassVar = Annotated[str, BeforeValidator(get_number_or_orig_value)]
    SafeInteger: ClassVar = Annotated[int, BeforeValidator(get_int_or_orig_value)]
    PlainText: ClassVar = Annotated[str, BeforeValidator(sanitise_plain_text)]
```

example data model

```
class Customer(MyBaseClass, extra='ignore'):

    first_name: Optional[MyBaseClass.PlainText] = None
    last_name: Optional[MyBaseClass.PlainText] = None
    address: Optional[MyBaseClass.PlainText] = None
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
first_name: Optional[MyBaseClass.PlainText, max_len=20] = None
```

I am not able to find any details on how one would provide a parameter to the validators